# Why Isn't My Height Tag Working?

Tags: css

So my below code works great, except that for some reason, the height tags on my images aren't taking properly. My images come out extremely squished, and I can't figure out why. What tag is messing it up?

My Code Snippet:

```css
/*IMAGE HOVER STYLE*/

ul.img-list {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
}
ul.img-list li {
  display: inline-block;
  height: 100px;
  margin: 0 1em 1em 0;
  position: relative;
  width: 100px;
}
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
}
span.text-content span {
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
}
ul.img-list li:hover span.text-content {
  opacity: 1;
}
span.text-content {
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  color: white;
  cursor: pointer;
  display: table;
  height: 100px;
  left: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100px;
  opacity: 0;
  -webkit-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -moz-transition: opacity 500ms;
  -o-transition: opacity 500ms;
  transition: opacity 500ms;
}
```

```html
<div align=center>
  <table border="0" style="margin-top: 10px; margin-bottom: 10px; margin-right: 50px; float: right; background-color: #708C91; opacity: 0.7; border:0px solid #708C91;color:#000000;width:700px;" cellpadding="10px" cellspacing="10px">
    <tr>
      <td>
        <center>Site Spotlights</center>
        <hr width=60% style="opacity:.7">
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <ul class="img-list">
          <li>
            <img src="http://i1371.photobucket.com/albums/ag312/MaxximusOzz/MOTM_zps3aa2f324.png" width="100" height="100" />
            <span class="text-content"><span>Member</span></span>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: What do you mean by "squished" exactly? What is the original size of the images, and what is the size when they are displayed in the browser?

Comment: The original images are 100 x 100. When they display, the 100 width takes properly with the code attached to the image. The height tag won't do anything, so the visual result is maybe 10px?

Answer (score 0):

There is no `height` attribute in the image.

```
heigth="100"
```

should be:

```
height="100"
```

Comment: Sorry, that's not the problem. I had been messing with it before I copy and pasted and spelled it wrong when I re-inserted it into my snippet. It is "height" in my code.

Comment: @TheHungerGamesTrilogyStaff: What does the actual code look like then? The code really needs an overhaul, by the way. You are mixing HTML with XHTML, there are some very outdated elements and attributes used, and there are CSS values in HTML attributes... and that's just from that small snippet... Validating the code would point you to loads of possible improvements.

Comment: Thanks for all your help. I updated the code to what it looks like. This should be all the relevant code pertaining to this problem. I'll run it through a validator and see if that helps. I am not a very experienced coder, so that's probably why a lot of different elements are thrown in there.

Comment: @TheHungerGamesTrilogyStaff: When I try out the code there is no problem displaying the image: http://jsfiddle.net/w1v0vfpL/ So, there is likely some other code that affects the image. You can use the developer tools in the browser to examine the image element, that will tell you what styles actually apply to it.

Comment: Thanks. Yeah, I was afraid it was some of the other code in the page.

Comment: Do you know what kind of code might affect that height tag? There's a lot of code that affects it when I inspect the element.

Comment: @TheHungerGamesTrilogyStaff: That would have to be something that affects the height of the image element itself. Anything that would limit the height in any other way would not squish the image.